# Как сделать пробный период платного продукта в Flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchases

Всем привет. Хотел узнать как я могу это реализовать с помощью `in_app_purchase` . У меня честно говоря нет проблем с кодом просто я хочу узнать какие надо фичи использовать, чтобы это сделать. И чтобы смогли понять о чем я говорю я прикреплю скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько помню, все это в товарах(подписках) настраивается. А дальше уже как обычно, проверяете подписку и работаете..

Comment: @CyberDemon вы имеете ввиду нижний popup Google play с оплатой?